# Как получить значение из строки?

Tags: python, json

Здравстуйте.

Вытащил из текста строку и перевел её в json-формат:

```
" articlesFromServer = [{\"ei\":262283959,\"mk\":\"Renault\",\"md\":\"Scenic\",\"cs\":\"€\",\"fr\":\"07/2000\",\"ot\":\"U\",\"at\":\"C\",\"ma\":\"244.264\",\"pd\":null,\"pp\":\"1,-\",\"iep\"
```

Вытащить нужно `262283959` и по всей строке (она длинная) еще несколько таких чисел, которые следуют после `\"ei\":`. Пробовал упростить через split, а также указать separators, но что-то никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Регулярные выражения.
2. Изменять строку.
   Например, можно так: 
   1) найти индекс (`idx`) подстроки `\"ei":` в строке;
   2) найти индекс (`s`) символа `,` в строке начиная с `idx`; 
   3) вырезать строку начиная от (`idx` + длина подстроки из 1-го шага) до `s`.
   P.S. Вариантов обработки строки может быть очень много.

Answer (score 2):

1) Регулярка:

```
import re
s = '[{"ei":262283959,"mk":"Renault","md":"Scenic"}]'
res = re.compile(r'(?<="ei":)\d+').findall(s)
print res[0]
```

2) Из строки убрать присваивание переменной `articlesFromServer =` значения списка и использовать библиотеку `json`:

```
import json
res = json.loads('[{"ei":262283959,"mk":"Renault","md":"Scenic"}]')
print res[0]['ei']
```

Примечание:
Если в строке все-таки есть экранирующие символы, то лучше сразу от них избавиться. Если ты скопировал строку ручками в файл `.py` и присвоил строке, например, `s` значение текста с экранирующими символами, то интерпретатор их сам уберет (например, от `s = '\"ei\"'` останется только `'"ei"'`).

Comment: +1 за использование `json` модуля. Не нужно использовать регулярные выражения, чтобы парсить известные форматы, такие как json. Хотя строка в вопросе, не является json.